# Need assistance in fixing SuspiciousFileOperation error in django2.0

Tags: python, django

It appears as if the uploaded images have broken links:

[image: Main page Myshop]

This is the actual error when the images are clicked:

[image]

I wanted to figure it out if i did something wrong on my list.html

```html
{% block title %} {% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %} {% endblock %} {% block content %}
<div id="sidebar">
  <h3>Categories</h3>
  <ul>
    <li {% if not category %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
      <a href="{% url " shop:product_list " %}">All</a>
    </li>
    {% for c in categories %}
    <li {% if category.slug==c .slug %}class="selected" {% endif %}>
      <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="main" class="product-list">
  <h1>{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products {% endif %}</h1>
  {% for product in products %}
  <div class="item">
    <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
      <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static " img/no_image.png " %}{% endif %}">
    </a>
    <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a>
    <br> R{{ product.price }}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My views are as follows:

[image: list all the products or filter products by a given category]

My models:

[image: managing catergories and products]

Comment: What's your media root path in your settings file? Did you use forward or backward slashes? I suspect there's nothing wrong with your views, html template etc, it's probably related to some changes related to os.path in Python 3.6.7 that isn't compatible with Django 2.

Comment: I used forward slashes  and here are my settings:                                                                              
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

Comment: Yeah, change them to backslashes or double backslashes and it should fix your problem.

Comment: I mean, MEDIA_ROOT forwardslash to double backslash . You can also delete it, I guess.

Comment: Borut, thank you so much, by removing the MEDIA_ROOT it works perfectly.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should remove MEDIA_ROOT completely, just the trailing (forward)slash. On Windows you should use double backslashes for paths, such as `C:\\Apache2\\wwwroot\\. No idea if this change is related to Python 3.6.7, but I faced the same issue as you did when I upgraded to version 3.6.7.

Comment: Yes, a slight changes on the upgrades i think it could be the problem. Thanks a lot Borut.

Answer (score 0):

The quoting on this section of code in your template is wrong:

```
     <img src="{% if product.image %} {{ product.image.url }} {% else %} 
         {% static 'img/no_image.png' %}{% endif %}">
```

I don't believe you can have conditionals like `{% if %}` inside double quotes.  Try this instead:

```
{% if product.image %}
    <img src="{{ product.image.url }}">
{% else %}
    <img src="{% static 'img/no_image.png' %}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi John Gordon, thanks for the reply in answering my question, how ever i still get the same error when i changed my code to the above you just provided.